# how can i get the php value(id) from a span and use it in a modal window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i created an articles and each article has an id. i made a modal window for viewing the detailed articles inside modal window you can insert a comment and like the article but the problem is when i tried to click the other article the id that he gets is only the first id that was created.what i wanted to do is that when i tried to click the article it will get the article id and show it to the modal.

here is my sample code.

this is the button that i clicked for me to show the modal window

```
 span style="color:#59960b;" class="read" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#myModal">Read more..</span><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $articleid; ?>"></span>
```

**MODAL WINDOW**

```
     <?php
                $output = $db->viewArticle($articleid);
                foreach ($output as $key):
                if($key['art_id'] == $articleid){   
        ?>
      <!--view Modal content-->
      <div id="articlepost" class="modal-content-article">
        <div class="modal-header-article">
            <input type="hidden" name="aid" id="aid" value="<?php echo $articleid ?>"/>
              <button type="button" style="padding-left:1155px;position:fixed;" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <img src="./<?= $key['art_cphoto'];?>" style="margin-left:100px;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div align="center"  style="color:#222;">   
                    <strong class="font-2" id="title"><?php echo $arttitle ?></strong>
        <?php }?>
        <?php

        foreach ($db->countarticlecomment($articleid) as $value) {

        ?>

        <span class="font-1-2" style="margin-right:10px;">
        <i class="fa fa-comment" style="color:#59960b;"></i> <span style="color:gray;"><b><?php echo $value['comments']?></b></span>&emsp;

        </span>
        <hr>
        <?php  }?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
        $out = $db->articleviewcount($articleid);
        foreach ( $db->viewarticlecomment() as $value) {
        if($articleid = $value['artid']){
        ?>

        <div  id="mycomments"  class="col-lg-8" style="background:#eff9c7;color:#222;margin-left:170px">
        <span class="" style="margin-left:10px;font-size:.9em;color:gray;"><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $value['artsend']?>"></abbr></span> 
        </p>
    </div>

    <?php
        }   
    }
    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="background:#eff9c7;margin-left:170px">
                        <br>
    <input type="text" name="artcomment" id="artcomment"  class="form-control pull-right" style="width:92%;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:10px;" placeholder="Comments..." />
                        <br><br>
                    </div>

            <?php endforeach ?>
                <br>
         <div class="row">

        </div>
        <br> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

how can i get the value of the $articleid so that when i clicked one of the articles it will send the (id)value to the modal window so that the id of the article will be the one to shown. i tried using jquery to get the $articleid and it works but my problem is how can i use the id from my jquery to my modal? i tried searching and they said to use ajax. i tried it also and declared my modal window in a variable but my concern is my modal has 2 forloops inside and also when i tried to use the jquery function only the latest article is clickable not the other articles. even if i can get the id of the article if i cannot clicked the other article it doesn't make anysense. so is there any way i can get the id and use it in a modal..? btw this script is both inside 1php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you use the Global data attribute to send the article id to the modal.  You can learn about the data attribute here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp.

Below is a code snippet that shows how the data attribute works.

You'll notice that in the button there is an custom data attribute called `data-articleid` and that I have set it's value to `xyz`.  You would set it's value to `<?php echo $articleid ?>`.  I can't use php here.

When the button `openBtn` is clicked, a function is called and a variable called `articleId` gets the value of the attribute `data-articleid` and then sets the text of `title` inside the modal to `articleId`.

```js
// function to open the modal, get the data attribute, and set the title text
$('#openBtn').click(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  var articleId = openBtn.getAttribute("data-articleid");
  $('#title').text(articleId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<!-- I can't use php in this snippet so I'm just hardcoding a data-articleid of "xyz".  You should echo your article id instead. -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-articleid="xyz" id="openBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could output all articles as their own modals and assign them their own ID's, so that they wouldn't be named as `myModal` (`<div id="myModal`) but instead `myModal1`, `myModal2`etc.

Then the links would look like this

```
<span style="color:#59960b;" class="read" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#myModal<?php echo $articleid; ?>">Read more..</span>
```

This would work if you don't have too many articles, if there is a lot of data, you should use Ajax.